# Service Fabric component usability based on Requirement

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-service-fabric

We have an requirement to invoke the Third party API(Yodlee) through Fabric service. It is Connecting Existing bank with yodlee service to get their  Transaction.

Here, to connect the yodlee, need to maintain the Token (30 min Expire) for all api invoking with header.

Please suggest the which component would use to match the scenario.

Approach 1:

Stateless WebApi (EndPoint) -> Stateful Service (to maintain the state (Token) for all Node.

Approach 2:

Stateless WebApi (EndPoint) -> Stateful Actor (to maintain the state (Token)

Approach 3:

Is there a way to crate the stateful service with Webapi

Approach 4:

Service bus -> Stateful service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach 2. Using an Actor is a simple way to store a token for a user. Use a `Reminder` to invalidate or refresh the token after expiry.

Maybe you can use the Actor as a proxy to Yodlee, by putting the Authentication/Autorization/GetTransaction calls inside it.

Comment: Thanks. 10 -15 Yodlee Endpoint API have to invoke to meet our requirement. can i create & access all api call  through Actor. or, Need to maintain the token info in Actor?

Comment: you can do either, take your favorite

Comment: Ok. I need to use two third party api(contis,Yodlee). Whether can i create two Stateless WebAPi for each one.